# Run function only if the values in the input exists

Tags: jquery

I have a form with input fields which return a calculated output on `keyup`. The issue is that I want the fields to execute the function only when all the input values are filled. Ideally, I did this by running the `keyup` function on the last input field and then return the value.

However, I also wanted to return the calculated result immediately when any of the field values were edited or updated.

How can I call the function only when all the values are filled, but also be able to call the function when I'm editing the values?

This is the code:

```js
$('#3').keyup(function(e) {
  $('.a').val(getRandomNumber());

});

function getRandomNumber() {
  return Math.random();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="texty" id="1" /> <br>
<input type="text" class="texty" id="2" /> <br>
<input type="text" class="texty" id="3" /> <br>
<input type="text" class="a" id="4" />
```

So in the above sample code I want the function `getRandomNumber` to be called only when all the input values with class `texty` are filled (i.e not empty). But once all the values are filled, if I edit any of the fields again, I want the function to be called again. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('.texty').keyup(function(e) {
  var getRandom = true;
  $.each($('.texty'),function(key , value){
    (!$(this).val().length)?
      getRandom = false:''
  });
  getRandom?$('.a').val(getRandomNumber()):'';
});

function getRandomNumber() {
  return Math.random();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="texty" id="1" /> <br>
<input type="text" class="texty" id="2" /> <br>
<input type="text" class="texty" id="3" /> <br>
<input type="text" class="a" id="4" />
```

Comment: You don't like `if` statements? Your use of ternaries is quite unusual.

Comment: @Barmar It's a somehow bad habit :(

Comment: Feel free to do as you like in your own code, but I suggest more mainstream style when posting here. I'm an expert coder and it took me a minute to figure out what you're doing, think about how confusing it must be to a newbie.

Comment: Spaces would also be nice.

Answer (score 2):

```js
$('#1').keyup(onkeyup);
$('#2').keyup(onkeyup);
$('#3').keyup(onkeyup);

function onkeyup(ev) {
  if ($('#1').val() && $('#2').val() && $('#3').val()) {
    $('.a').val(getRandomNumber());
  }
}

function getRandomNumber() {
  return Math.random();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="texty" id="1" /> <br>
<input type="text" class="texty" id="2" /> <br>
<input type="text" class="texty" id="3" /> <br>
<input type="text" class="a" id="4" />
```